# Remove blank space at the beginning and end of a text (not in between)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a chat app, and I want to remove blank space from user input at the beginning and at the end of a message.

so -> "BLANKSPACE   hi my name is BLANKSPACE  Matthias    BLANKSPACE"
should be "hi my name is  BLANKSPACE Matthias".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one can help you if you don't show any code

Comment: Not true. Schokokuchen helped me perfectly (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is called trimming.
In flutter (which uses [dart](https://www.dartlang.org/)) you can use:
`'\t  hi my name is     Matthias \n '.trim();` which will result in `'hi my name is     Matthias'`.

[dart: String.trim()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/String/trim.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know of trimming. Any idea how I can keep the whitespace between the words (I even want the user be able to have like 4 spacebars between words or insert a paragraph)? I only want to trim at the beginning of the text and at the end (same as WhatsApp).

Comment: I just tested it - you're completely right. It does not remove any blank space in-between. Any chance I can also measure, if user has only hit enter e.g. 5 times (and has not written any text)?

Comment: `trim()` will also take care of that, since it removes linebreaks. You can just test if the trimmed string has a length of 0.